# super() in Java. What does it mean?

Tags: java, super, inheritance

I'm a little bit confused by this code:

```
class A{
    class B{
    }
}

class C extends A.B{
    C(A a){
        a.super();
    }
}
```

What does it mean: "a.super();" ? 
Before i thought super - link to her parent class, but "super()" - link to parent's constructor, but really class A haven't a parent class(don't mind Object...), so what does it mean super in this context?

Thx everybody.

Answer (score 5):

super() calls the default constructor of the super class. If you don't define a constructor your class always has a invisible default constructor, which doesn't require any parameters. You are calling the constructor of the Object class in this case.

Comment: No, it's wrong. I thought the same. But, actually 
`a.super()` = `A.B()`, so B's class constructor. I found it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2831567/2572927

And i found one interest moment:

`class A{
    class B{
        B(String s){print(s);}
    }
}

class C extends A.B{
    C(A a){
        a.super("C constructor!");
    }
}`

It's normal work, so 'a.super()' = 'A.B()'. I think so, i hope it's truth=)

Answer (score 3):

It is qualified superclass constructor invocation.

From the [JLS 1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

> Explicit constructor invocation statements can be divided into two kinds:
>
> 1. Alternate constructor invocations begin with the keyword this (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.
> 2. Superclass constructor invocations begin with either the keyword super (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments) or a Primary expression. They are used to invoke a constructor of the direct superclass. Superclass constructor invocations may be further subdivided:
> 3. Unqualified superclass constructor invocations begin with the keyword super (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments).
> 4. **Qualified superclass constructor invocations begin with a Primary expression . They allow a subclass constructor to explicitly specify the newly created object's immediately enclosing instance with respect to the direct superclass (§8.1.3). This may be necessary when the superclass is an inner class.**