# inner class inheritence using super keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, nested, super

```
class ClassA
{
class NestedA{};
}

class class B extends ClassA.NestedA
{
B(ClassA instanceA)      // non-default constructor
{
instanceA.super();       //1
};
}
```

I read this code in a book but couldn't understand meaning of line marked 1.
I haven't ever come across this type of call to constructor of super type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Non-static nested classes and instance.super()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831484/java-non-static-nested-classes-and-instance-super)

Comment: Thanks I m checking out that question ..