# Why do method() and super.method() refer to different things in an anonymous subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I was solving some exercises to understand better how inner classes in java work. I found one quite interesting exercise. The condition of the exercise is to make `printName()` print "sout" instead of "main" with minimum changes. There is its code:

```
public class Solution {
    private String name;

    Solution(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void sout() {
        new Solution("sout") {
            void printName() {
                System.out.println(getName());
                // the line above is an equivalent to:
                // System.out.println(Solution.this.getName);
            }
        }.printName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solution("main").sout();
    }
}
```

We've got an amusing situation - the two classes have is-A and has-A connections.
    It means that the anonymous inner class extends the outer class and also objects of the inner class have references to the objects of the outer class.
    If you run the code above, "main" will be printed. The child cannot invoke `getName()` of the parent through inheritance. But the child being inner class uses reference to parent(outer class) to access the method.

The simplest way to solve this task is to change the access modifier of `getName()` from `private` to anything else. So the child is able to use `getName()` through inheritance and thanks to late binding "sout" will be printed.

The another way to solve this task is to use `super.getName()`.

```
private void sout() {
    new Solution("sout") {
        void printName() {
            System.out.println(super.getName());
        }
    }.printName();
}
```

And I cannot understand how it works. Can someone help me to understand this problem?

Thank you for trying)

Comment: What version of Java are you using? 10?

Comment: I'm using 8th version.

Comment: Please tell us which of the elements in the code above you don't understand. Does not seem like a rocket science to me.

Comment: I don't understand what means super.getName() in this particular situation.

Comment: check this may be gives you idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831484/java-non-static-nested-classes-and-instance-super

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java Language Specification (JLS), [in the context of the compiler resolving a method invocation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1), states

> If the form is `super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then the class to
>   search is the superclass of the class whose declaration contains the
>   method invocation.

The class *whose declaration contains the method invocation*, in this case, is the anonymous `Solution` subclass and its superclass is `Solution`. The JLS, [in the context of determining which instance will be used to invoke the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1), then goes on to say

> If the form is `super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then the target
>   reference is the value of `this`.

`this`, in this case, refers to the instance of the anonymous `Solution` subclass. That instance's `name` field was initialized with the value `"sout"` as so that is what `getName()` returns.

---

In the original sample,

```
new Solution("sout") {
    void printName() {
        System.out.println(getName());
    }
}.printName();
```

the `getName()` method invocation is unqualified and therefore a different rule applies. That is

> If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a
>   member, let `T` be the innermost such type declaration. The class or
>   interface to search is `T`.

`T`, here, is the `Solution` class, since it is the innermost enclosing type of the anonymous `Solution` subclass and `getName()` is its member.

Then, the JLS states

> Otherwise, let `T` be the enclosing type declaration of which the method
>   is a member, and let `n` be an integer such that `T` is the n'th lexically
>   enclosing type declaration of the class whose declaration immediately
>   contains the method invocation. The target reference is the n'th
>   lexically enclosing instance of `this`.

Again, `T` is `Solution`, the 1st lexically enclosing type since the class whose declaration immediately contains the method invocation is the anonymous `Solution` subclass. `this` is the anonymous `Solution` subclass instance. The target reference is therefore the 1st lexically enclosing instance of `this`, ie. the `Solution` instance, whose `name` field was initialized with the value `"main"`. That's why the original code prints `"main"`.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior may seem counter-intuitive but it becomes clear with a bit of refactoring.

So, the `sout()` method can actually be rewritten as

```
private void sout() {
  new Solution("sout") {
    void printName() {
      String name = getName();
      System.out.println(name);
    }
  }.printName();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Solution mainSolution = new Solution("main");
  mainSolution.sout();
}
```

Calling the `sout()` method of the `mainSolution` object, creates a child `Solution` object that has an additional `printName()` method, which calls

`getName();`

which only declared in the parent `mainSolution` object.

If `getName()` is declared as private, it is not overriden but it is still accessible from the inner class, so `getName()` refers to the name of the `mainSolution`, i.e. to `main`.

If `getName()` has no modifier, or is declared as protected or public, then it is inherited (overriden) and refers to the child `Solution` object's name, i.e. to `sout`, hence "sout" will be printed.

By replacing `getName()` in `sout()` with

```
Solution.this.getName()
```

the string "main" will be printed in both scenarios.

By replacing it with either of

```
this.getName()
super.getName()
```

if the `getName()` method is declared as `private` a compilation error will occur, otherwise the string "sout" will be printed.

Comment: if `getName()` has `private` access and  `this.getName()` is used, then a compilation error will occur. 
But if `getName()` has `private` access and `super.getName()` is used, then "sout" will be printed.

Comment: Exactly. That's what the answer above says, too. :-)